# Draw borders 200m left and right of a line

Tags: qgis

I just installed QGIS for I'm trying to do the following.

I've made a layer from a GPX file. So the result is I see a line on a map. Now I want to add two 'boundaries'. I want to make a line 200 meters left and right of it, following the route of course.

Or

Make the route line 400 meter thick with a center line and a transparent color. I saw where I could edit the layer line but it doesn't seem to be able to do this

Does someone have a pointer on how to do this?

The goals is to then try and load the line with map back into e.g. a garmin device to take the route but stick in the boundaries

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the 2nd scenario, you can use a line symbol made of two simple line markers, one with an offset of +200m and the other one with an offset of -200m. Make sure to have your data projected in a CRS using meters, and to select the `map unit` option.
I have no idea if such style can be brought back to your GPS unit though..

[image: Positive and negative line offset styling]

PS: the dashed line is the original line position displayed on a copy of the layer, but you can easily integrate it to the style as 3rd simple line marker with no offset

Comment: Thanks. I'll try that. I think I know why it hadn't worked before. I haven' done anything yet with CRS

Answer (score 2):

As to your first scenario, my suggestion is to use `GRASS v.parallel` tool;

1. Reproject your GPX line layer (Geographic: Latlong) to XY coordinates so that the map unit is meter, and save it as new Shapefile. One possible choice would be EPSG:3857 ("pseudo mercator") which is easily overlaid with background maps such as QuickMapServices plugin.
2. Start new QGIS project and reload the Line Shapefile you have just saved. (Your project CRS is now EPSG:3857).
3. From `Processing Toolbox`, activate `GRASS | Vector | v.parallel`. Set both (major & minor) offsets to 200 (m). `Side` option should be "both". 
   [Run] this tool.
4. Newly created parallel lines would appear on the map. Save this layer as GPX. Do not forget to set the target CRS to EPSG:4326.